# vb.net winforms design / layout issue

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I am working on a windows forms project that will allow a user to have an interface to the database, and another will be a nightly run process file that will update the database table.

The user will add new records to the table, whereas the nightly process will update the columns with new values (think mortgage interest rates)

Both these projects will be using the same business logic component that has the calculations needed to enter values into the table.

The way I am figuring this out, is that I will have two exe's (one for the interface and one for the nightly process) and have a central object that will host the calculations. What would be the best object for this purpose?

A class file?
A windows service? (I want to stay away from a windows service, because it will have to be running all the time)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.

The central object with your business logic components should be a Class Library project (outputting a DLL).

The Winform project that allows users to interface with the database should reference (and use) your Class Library project.

The nightly process should run a Windows Console Application that would also reference and use your Class Library project.  Like Davita suggests the nightly process should be called from a Windows Scheduled Task.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly your question, you can consider Windows Task Scheduler. You create a job which will execute your exe at any given time of day.